# Awkward button positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to create an `input-group` with a form input and my submit button using Bootstrap 5.

My code:

```css
.card {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.9!important;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">Login</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-prepend">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-append">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

However, the issue is that my button is very awkardly sized and is a bit higher from the input form.
Picture
[image]

How'd I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add  `align-items-end` to `input-group`

```css
.card {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 46rem;">
  <div class="card-header">Login</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 align-items-end"> 
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-prepend">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-append">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```